# JQuery Ajax, sending parameter with backslash

Tags: php, ajax, backslash

I am using on my web page input array:

```
<input id='idInput[1]' />
```

And with some JavaScript function I am able to set the value of this input:

```
$('#idInput\[1\]').val(5);
```

Problem is that the ID of input which I want to set I have to send back to server (using AJAX) and after it send back the response, but because of backslash I need to add so many backslash because of AJAX processing, PHP processing and the end jQuery processing. So at the end it looks like:

```
ajaxSetIdWithResult("idInput\\\\\\\\[1\\\\\\\\]");
```

With this solution it is working well but I feel that is horrible. So can do it better?

Comment: Why are you constructing id like `'idInput[1]'`

Comment: `I am using on my web page input array` - I'm not sure if you aren't confusing setting the name attribute of an input/textarea to allow for parsing as an array, ie. `<input name="foo[]" value="one"><input name="foo[]" value="two">`. The same cannot be done for IDs, simply because there is no need to parse IDs in such a way. Why not simply use an ID naming scheme like `id="idInput-1"`, or `id="idInput_1"`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I am a little bit overwork. You are right I can use [1] for name because of processing in PHP but for ID it can be just id_1 or id-1, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
instead #idInput[1] change id like below


<input id='idInput_1' />
```